# Scene builder custom components being expanded in fxml

Tags: java, javafx-2, javafx-8, scenebuilder

I've been using JavaFX for a couple months now, and I must say that I really like it. However, recently, I've been trying to make custom components with scene builder.

Lets say I have my custom component called a CustomTable which looks something like this

```
public class CustomTable extends VBox{

public CustomTable(){
    try {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("CustomTable.fxml"));
        loader.setRoot(this);
        loader.setController(this);
        loader.load();
    } catch (IOException e ){
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

}

and I have the corresponding FXML file

```
<fx:root prefHeight="444.0" prefWidth="472.0" type="VBox" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="CustomTable">
<children>
    <TableView maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="410.0" prefWidth="297.0" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
        <columns>
            <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="Testing Column 1" />
            <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="Testing Column 2" />
        </columns>
        <columnResizePolicy>
            <TableView fx:constant="CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY" />
        </columnResizePolicy>
    </TableView>
</children>
```

Now if I import this CustomTable into Scene builder, it allows me to use it just like a regular component. So if I make a new view and drag it onto that view I get something like this.

```
<GridPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity"
minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="436.0" prefWidth="621.0"
xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8">
<columnConstraints>
    <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0"
        prefWidth="100.0" />
    <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0"
        prefWidth="100.0" />
</columnConstraints>
<rowConstraints>
    <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0"
        vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
</rowConstraints>
<children>
    <VBox prefHeight="444.0" prefWidth="472.0" GridPane.columnIndex="1">
        <children>
            <TableView maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308"
                minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="410.0"
                prefWidth="297.0" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
                <columns>
                    <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="Testing Column 1" />
                    <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="Testing Column 2" />
                </columns>
                <columnResizePolicy>
                    <TableView fx:constant="CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY" />
                </columnResizePolicy>
            </TableView>
        </children>
    </VBox>
    <Button mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="38.0" prefWidth="94.0"
        text="TEST" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" />
</children>
```

I don't think it makes sense for the component to be expanded out. I feel like it should be like this.

```
<GridPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity"
minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="436.0" prefWidth="621.0"
xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8">
<columnConstraints>
    <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0"
        prefWidth="100.0" />
    <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0"
        prefWidth="100.0" />
</columnConstraints>
<rowConstraints>
    <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0"
        vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
</rowConstraints>
<children>
    <CustomTable GridPane.columnIndex="1" prefHeigh="444.0"
        prefWidth="472.0" />
    <Button mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="38.0" prefWidth="94.0"
        text="TEST" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" />
</children>
```

Does anyone know how to make the custom component from expanding when put into scene builder, or is this a bug / feature that hasn't been fixed / implemented yet? I feel like this is very crucial for making reusable custom components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some investigation, I realized my issue. I was importing the FXML directly, which of course would make sense that the FXML gets expanded. The proper solution is to JAR both the class and FXML together and import that jar file. This will produce the right behavior.